# What Azure resources uses TLS

Tags: azure, azure-storage, tls1.2

I received an email from Microsoft that mentioned I should ensure that any interactions with Azure services are using TLS 1.2 by 31 October 2024. (older versions of TLS will end by this date).

I currently have a bunch of resources / subscriptions in my tenant, but am not sure which ones use TLS.

I was wondering is there a way to generate a list of resources that may use a version of TLS? Or is there a reference of resources that use TLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To list the resources which are using the TLS version, run the below commands in PowerShell:**

```
1. Install-Module -Name Az.ResourceGraph

2. Connect-AzAccount
```

- Query to ***list the resources*** that use ***TLS 1.2***.

```
Search-AzGraph -Query "Resources | where properties.minimumTlsVersion == 'TLS1_2' | project name, type, properties.minimumTlsVersion"
```

**Response:**

```
name                     type                              properties_minimumTlsVersion
----                     ----                              ----------------------------
689314                   microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
adXXstorage21            microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
aXXXXstorageanalytics    microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
aXXXXXXXXanalytics123    microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
aXXXXXXgen2cshaik        microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
aXXXXXXXXgen2may15       microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
aXXXXXXXXgensubm         microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
aXstorageaccount         microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
XXXstore01               microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
assiststorageaccount     microsoft.storage/storageaccounts   TLS1_2
```

[image]

Comment: That works fine for storage accounts, but not getting any results for any other resource types